# How can I set in the code height for inner LinearLayouts to be exactly 1/5 of its parent LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I define all GUI components in the code without xml layout file. I have main linear layout and 5 inner layouts into it. The code:

```
LinearLayout llMain = new LinearLayout (this);
llMain.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT ));
llMain. setOrientation (LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
llMain.setWeightSum(1.0f);

LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.weight = 0.2f

ll1.setLayoutParams(lp);

llMain.addView(ll1);

....
....
```

But it doesn't give the expected result. The ll1 inner layout has about 70% of the height of llMain layout instead of 20%. So, how can I set height of inner ll1 layout to be exactly 1/5 of the height of its parent llMain layout? Thanks.

Comment: I see that the change of the constant in the second argument in lp definition to "WRAP_CONTENT" instead of "FILL_PARENT" , gave me better result. I still don't have exactly 1/5 of the parent layout height, but now it is very close to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
lp.weight = 0.2f;
```

Can you try this and let us know the result?

Comment: Hi Shadow, thanks. I think that I found other solution, I'll write it as question comment.

Comment: Hi again, you are right. Actually it should be lp.weight=0.2f. I have it in source code, but I wrote with mistake in in the question. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I dont' remember wrong there's a really cool trick about this. I remember it from Google I/O talks. You have to give to all members of the content layout_height equals 0 and then you have to use layout_weight to give the correct percentage (in this case layout_weight=20).

Try to do this trick :)

Comment: Hi StErMi, it looks interesting. I tried it right now, but I received some strange result. When I switch avd device to landscape orientation, the row with this tricky layout disappears.

Comment: Uhm strange I don't remember where I hear this trick but I'm pretty sure that was from a Google I/O talk. Take a look here: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: Hi StErMi, thanks for the link. I see that it is a very good lecture, and I could study additional things from there. I'll try again and update later about this trick.